# Jquery set option tag to selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following HTML:

```
<select id="select_test" class="form-control select2" name="searchValue[]" multiple >
    <optgroup label="Offers">
        <option>option 1</option>
        <option id="wtf">option 3</option>
        <option>option 4</option>
        <option>option 5</option>
        <option>option 6</option>
        <option>option 7</option>
        <option>option 8</option>
        <option>option 9</option>
        <option>option 10</option>
        <option>option 11</option>
        <option>option 12</option>
        <option>option 13</option>
        <option>option 14</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Now i want to set the id `"wtf"` to selected

for this i created the following javascript / jquery:

```
$('#wtf').attr('selected',true);
```

However this failed so i tried:

```
$('#wtf').attr('selected','selected');
```

Same resuls.

What am i doing wrong?

**my full javascript**

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {


    $("#select_test").select2({});
    $('#wtf').prop('selected',true);
});
```

Comment: use `$('#select_test').val('option 3')` instead

Comment: `$('#wtf').prop('selected',true);`

Comment: Although yes, you should use prop - attr works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/EDAkM/

Comment: attr should work.. but it's better to use prop for this.. where have you put your code.. try with  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wtf').attr('selected','selected');
    });

Comment: @PsychHalf thats most likley the problem +1

Comment: @Anton yeah.. coz  you don't get errors on console on $("#wtf") if #wtf doesnt exsist..

Comment: Linking my full javascript

Comment: @Marc Oh you are using select2 if i remember correctly you can't select like that, i'll update my answer as soon as i remember what you had to do

Comment: @Anton lol thanks i should prob. have mentioned that!

Comment: @Marc if you are using a jQuery plugin.. you should have included that in your question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using prop

```
$('#wtf').prop('selected',true);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/5nj5m/)

**Update**

To select with select2 use must use .select2().select2('val','option') like this

```
$("#select_test").select2().select2('val','option3');
```

or with id

```
$('#select_test').select2().select2('val',$('#wtf').text());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/6hZFU/82/)

Comment: @Marc Are you getting any erros in your console or do you have multiple elements with the id "wtf"?

Comment: @Marc have you wrapped document.ready around your code like PsychHalf said in the comment

Comment: Yes. it removes the options and it is wrapped yes